# SSDT Blow Up on Removing Temporal Tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

Visual Studio 2019 - SSDT 16.0.

I have 8 tables in a Dev database that were originally temporal. I removed the temporal portion of the table syntax and the project refused to build. I deleted the database and ran the project Transact for these tables in SSMS and all the Create Tables work. Deleted the database again and attempted to publish and the build failed. For each of the eight tables in the project that I converted to standard tables I receive an error message such as:

> incorrect syntax near ]

on AircraftHistoryDetail.

The double click modal on the error says:

> Cannot find file MSSQL:AircraftHistoryDetail.

Here is the code on the AircraftDetails table:

```
CREATE TABLE [deploy].[AircraftDetail]
(
    AircraftDetailId        INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    NameId                  INT,
    ProfileID               INT,
    ConstructionNumber      VARCHAR(50),
    ManufactureDate         VARCHAR(50),
    Model                   VARCHAR(50),
    Operator                VARCHAR(150),
    PreviousTailNumber      VARCHAR(50),
    ManufacturerSerialNumber VARCHAR(50),
    TailNumber              VARCHAR(50),
    [InactiveDate]          DATE   NULL,
    [CreatedFileDate] DATE         NULL,    
    CONSTRAINT PK_deploy_AircraftDetail PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AircraftDetailId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT FK_deploy_AircraftDetail FOREIGN KEY (NameId)
        REFERENCES deploy.[Name] (NameId)
);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the publish script, not necessarily your table definitions, for where the syntax error might be located? When the publish fails, click the View Script and then copy/paste what VS is trying to execute on SQL Server and maybe you can spot the problem, at least that's helped me in the past.

Comment: Thank You for the pointer but any attempt to publish produces the error modal - build failed. I have removed  the AircraftDetail file from the project, removed the table from the DB, cleaned the project and attempted a rebuild. Same errors as before with visual studio telling me the error is on a file AircraftHistoryDetail that does not exist in the project. I will be reverting to backup copies of all 8 files today.

Comment: try to remove from solution: all jfm files, all dbmdl files, all bin folders, all obj folders. Then clean solution and hit rebuild

Comment: For anyone looking at this, deleting obj and bin did nothing, but I deleted the project's jfm and dbmdl files and that worked with a rebuild. Not sure which of those two is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I reverted to backup copies of the versioned tables syntax and then got a good build and publish. Thank you for your comments. This looks to be an issue with SSDT.